# Google anlytics code doesn't track ajax generated page

Tags: ajax, google-analytics

In my site we have only one default.aspx page and we renders each htm pages into default.aspx. now we have added google anlytics code into each htm pages but google analytics report only shows one page default.aspx in tracking.  anyone can help on this how we can track for each page?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Sagar

Comment: Post the code, or it didnt happen

Answer (score 0):

To be more precise, Google Analytics tracking code is a pure JavaScript application. It measures page views by calling the `_trackPageview` function of the tracker object. Since very likely you embedded the tracking code in your static template (which is absolutely good), the `_trackPageview` only gets invoked on the document load. Though if your application deals with AJAX calls, you have to take care of reporting that virtual page views back to Analytics as [Deviant already pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833087/google-anlytics-code-doesnt-track-ajax-generated-page/833092#833092).